# How does the game determine what box a caught Pokemon will be sent to?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

Title says it all. It seems to be random and is really annoying.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Pokemon will be sent to the *last active* box (i.e. the last box that you looked at). If this box is full, Pokemon will be deposited in the next box up (e.g. if your last active box was Box 23 and it is full, Pokemon will be sent to Box 24).

Comment: You had the most words in your answer (1 more than Ben's). Plus Ben has too much rep already :P Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

It's the last box you left the Organize Boxes/etc menu on or, if that box is full, the next box with available space.

To avoid them being dumped in the wrong boxes, move your PC back to the "dump" box (which I usually put at the front of the boxes)

Comment: 3 identical answers within 14 seconds. New record??

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vx7-4j_TMx8

Comment: So how the heck am I supposed to pick an answer to accept? O.o

Comment: @Kecoey Roll a die. If you get a number between 1 and 6 inclusive, accept Yuki's answer. In all seriousness, don't worry about it.

Answer (score 12):

It sends to the last box you had open at the PC. If it is full, it moves to the next box until it finds an open slot.